# Transfer of Moments down a Column

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

I'm designing a column for a multi-storey structure. On each level of the structure, moments are transferred to it from beams which are fully fixed to the column. At the first floor (i.e. one level up from the ground floor) it is fully fixed about the minor axis and pinned about the major axis.

When considering moments acting in the bottom segment of the beam, are moments from all storeys transferred down? Or does the pinned/fixed end condition mean that we only need to consider moments from the first floor in either the major or minor axis (or both)?

I've tried to look this question up and so far have found nothing, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The key concept here is how the horizontal beams are connected to the column.

Pin and fixed to my understanding have a totally different meaning. With the pinned connection moments shouldn't transfer onto the column. While the fixed connection with essentially make a frame and the moments will all transfer to the columns.

|  | pinned | fixed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bending moment on horizontal beams (Assuming a concentrated load) | [image] | [image] |

Regarding the moments they will add up for increasing storeys. That means that **if it were only for  the bending moments** then the pinned structure would have zero bending moment.

However, for deformable structures the bending of the horizontal beams will create horizontal forces which will in turn create bending moments on the column. Those also stuck up. So in a **very simple model** of the each column would have something like the following shear force and bending moment diagram:

|  | Lateral load | bending moment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pinned beam | [image] | [image] |

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The beams are described as fully fixed (welded) onto the column, so they definitely do transfer a moment onto the column. I'm just wondering about how these moments travel down the column if the column is pinned/fixed part way down

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The above is a typical first-floor steel framing plan, that consists of a "moment frame" in the short direction and a "braced frame" in the long direction, and the respective deformed elevation views.

In the short direction, the continuity (to pass forces) of the frame is maintained by the rigid beam-column joint; but in the long direction, the simply connected beam-column joints will prevent the beams from fully participating in passing force carried by the column due to the lack of both the lateral and rotational restrains, thus instability could result; however, the instability and large lateral displacement of the frame can be prevented by the addition of the diagonal braces, which acting as the truss member to carry the lateral thrust, the moment will then be passed to the support below due to the continuity of the column.

Does this explain?